# cesiumjs and react app with craco start not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, cesiumjs, npm-scripts

I'm using npm "craco" in order to use "Resium" which is a react help library for cesiumjs maps.
[npm craco](https://github.com/darwin-education/craco-cesium)
I've copied all the files (except node_modules) to another folder, running npm i and npm start and it failed with these errors.
(The original folder works well but I need to duplicate it in order to share it and the node_modules not in the same size but the craco fold[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ1fr.png)er still there)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the webpack for some reason it instals different version that one of the dependencies needs, so 
I've switched to yarn and it works.